# Javascript/jquery and CSS minifier source c#

Tags: c#, javascript, html, css, minify

I want to know that how can i compress css/javascript/jquery and some html pages. By selecting folder it convert all related files to min. files. (is there any library developed in C#?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're looking for source code, you're at the wrong place

Comment: why i am at wrong place? is there anything in stackoverflow says "DO NOT ASK for CODE"? than plz send me that link..? so, next time i can't ask abt it.

Comment: You are not in the wrong place. You were just unlucky to run into ***. Have a look at this question, it covers javascript (jQuery included) and css. You don't need to minify html pages, the server should send it to the client by zipping it, that's enough. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4234213/340760

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/h5bp/ant-build-script

The HTML5 Boilerplate ant script is great.